# Oracle SQL: Selecting records where multiple columns could contain multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how to brute-force a solution to this; I'm mostly looking for an elegant solution to increase my own knowledge for the future.

I have a data table with 20 code flag fields.  (CODE_01, CODE_02, CODE_03, ..., CODE_20)

I am looking for records where *any* of those code columns contain certain values (eg: 11, 12, 24, 141, etc.)

I can do it like this:

```
Select * from table
where CODE_01 IN (11, 12, 24, 141)
   or CODE_02 IN (11, 12, 24, 141)
   or ...
   or CODE_20 IN (11, 12, 24, 141);
```

Or like this:

```
Select * from table
where 11 IN (CODE_01, CODE_02, ..., CODE_20)
   or 12 IN (CODE_01, CODE_02, ..., CODE_20)
   or 24 IN (CODE_01, CODE_02, ..., CODE_20)
   or 141 IN (CODE_01, CODE_02, ..., CODE_20);
```

Both work and are just exercises in copy/pasting.  I'm wondering if there's anything similar to this:

```
Select * from table
where (11, 12, 24, 141) IN (CODE_01, CODE_02, ..., CODE_20);
```

or

```
Select * from table
where (CODE_01, CODE_02, ..., CODE_20) IN (11, 12, 24, 141);
```

Theoretically I could concatenate the 20 fields and search that with a regular expression, I suppose, but I'm betting that's a pretty inefficient (and slow) query to run.

Thanks

Comment: Gosh, if your database were properly normalized, then the query would be easy.  Seriously, if this is the type of query that you are running, then you should have a `codes` table, with one code per row per entity.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not *my* database. :)  And I agree with you that the data should be normalized.  But it's a commercial product that I have read-only access to.  So no temp tables, no modifications possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with @GorndonLinoff that creating a `code` table would probably be the "right" solution, here's a trick you could try without changing your tables' structure:

If the relevant values are known when you're writing the query, you can replace the inline list with a set of `UNION`-ized queries from `dual`, and then join that on your table, utilizing the `IN` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
JOIN   (SELECT 11 as val FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 12 as val FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 24 as val FROM dual
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 141 as val FROM dual)
ON     val IN (code_01, code_02, ... code_20);
```

Of course, you can always replace the series of `SELECT`s from `dual` with  a temp table, but this is the basic idea.

I created a (considerably) simplified demonstration on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/78af1/10), if you want to play with it a bit.

Comment: This one looked the most like what I was looking for.  The values I'm searching for are all known, and while 8 'select from dual's is a bit longer than (11 or 12 or 24...), it's still only mentioning the 8 values once, and the 20 columns once within the sql.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this would be faster, but you might try

```
select * from table t
where exists 
 (Select * From 
   (Select PK, CODE_01 code from table Union 
    Select PK, CODE_02 code from table Union 
    Select PK, CODE_03 code from table Union 
    Select PK, CODE_04 code from table Union 
    ...
    Select PK, CODE_19 code from table Union 
    Select PK, CODE_20 code from table) z
  Where z.PK = t.PK
     And z.code in (11, 12, 24, 141))
```

or...

```
select * from table t
  join (Select PK, CODE_01 code Union 
        Select PK, CODE_02 code Union 
        Select PK, CODE_03 code Union 
        Select PK, CODE_04 code Union 
        ...
        Select PK, CODE_19 code Union 
        Select PK, CODE_20 code) z
    On z.PK = t.PK
Where z.code in (11, 12, 24, 141))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to unpivot the data (11g):

```
with test_data as (
  select 1 as id, 10 as code1, 11 as code2, 12 as code3 from dual
  union all
  select 2 as id, 10 as code1, 14 as code2, 20 as code3 from dual
  union all
  select 3 as id, 10 as code1, 14 as code2, 30 as code3 from dual
)
select distinct id
from test_data t
unpivot (code_value for codes in (code1, code2, code3))
where code_value in (11, 30);
```

This will return the ids for row 1 and 3.